# Maybe someone can help to change mysql to mysqli with fetch_array?

Tags: php, sql

```
<?php
include('conexion.php');

$año = $_POST['año'];

$enero = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT SUM(monto_venta) AS r FROM ventas WHERE MONTH(fecha_venta)=1 AND YEAR(fecha_venta)='$año'"));
$febrero = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT SUM(monto_venta) AS r FROM ventas WHERE MONTH(fecha_venta)=2 AND YEAR(fecha_venta)='$año'"));
$marzo = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT SUM(monto_venta) AS r FROM ventas WHERE MONTH(fecha_venta)=3 AND YEAR(fecha_venta)='$año'"));
$abril = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT SUM(monto_venta) AS r FROM ventas WHERE MONTH(fecha_venta)=4 AND YEAR(fecha_venta)='$año'"));
$mayo = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT SUM(monto_venta) AS r FROM ventas WHERE MONTH(fecha_venta)=5 AND YEAR(fecha_venta)='$año'"));
$junio = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT SUM(monto_venta) AS r FROM ventas WHERE MONTH(fecha_venta)=6 AND YEAR(fecha_venta)='$año'"));
$julio = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT SUM(monto_venta) AS r FROM ventas WHERE MONTH(fecha_venta)=7 AND YEAR(fecha_venta)='$año'"));
$agosto = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT SUM(monto_venta) AS r FROM ventas WHERE MONTH(fecha_venta)=8 AND YEAR(fecha_venta)='$año'"));
$septiembre = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT SUM(monto_venta) AS r FROM ventas WHERE MONTH(fecha_venta)=9 AND YEAR(fecha_venta)='$año'"));
$octubre = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT SUM(monto_venta) AS r FROM ventas WHERE MONTH(fecha_venta)=10 AND YEAR(fecha_venta)='$año'"));
$noviembre = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT SUM(monto_venta) AS r FROM ventas WHERE MONTH(fecha_venta)=11 AND YEAR(fecha_venta)='$año'"));
$diciembre = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT SUM(monto_venta) AS r FROM ventas WHERE MONTH(fecha_venta)=12 AND YEAR(fecha_venta)='$año'"));

$data = array(
    0 => round($enero['r'],1),
    1 => round($febrero['r'],1),
    2 => round($marzo['r'],1),
    3 => round($abril['r'],1),
    4 => round($mayo['r'],1),
    5 => round($junio['r'],1),
    6 => round($julio['r'],1),
    7 => round($agosto['r'],1),
    8 => round($septiembre['r'],1),
    9 => round($octubre['r'],1),
    10 => round($noviembre['r'],1),
    11 => round($diciembre['r'],1)
);           

echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Try to do charts with chats.js and find a good example, but the problem is that I can't change mysql to mysqli, maybe someone can help me  ? 
Thanks

Comment: what is you connection variable?

Comment: it is better to use prepared mysqli statements to avoid mysql injection

Comment: put your conexion.php code so that we can see it.

Comment: <?php
$conexion = mysql_connect('localhost', 'avalos12', 'avalos12');
mysql_select_db('dg', $conexion);
?>

Comment: @Giedrius your `conexion.php` is not in mysqli, try this. `<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
} >?` this is in MySQLi Procedural.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
include('conexion.php');

$año = $_POST['año'];

$enero = mysqli_query($conx,"SELECT SUM(monto_venta) AS r FROM ventas WHERE MONTH(fecha_venta)=1 AND YEAR(fecha_venta)='$año'");
$febrero = mysqli_query($conx,"SELECT SUM(monto_venta) AS r FROM ventas WHERE MONTH(fecha_venta)=2 AND YEAR(fecha_venta)='$año'");
$marzo = mysqli_query($conx,"SELECT SUM(monto_venta) AS r FROM ventas WHERE MONTH(fecha_venta)=3 AND YEAR(fecha_venta)='$año'");
$abril = mysqli_query($conx,"SELECT SUM(monto_venta) AS r FROM ventas WHERE MONTH(fecha_venta)=4 AND YEAR(fecha_venta)='$año'");
$mayo = mysqli_query($conx,"SELECT SUM(monto_venta) AS r FROM ventas WHERE MONTH(fecha_venta)=5 AND YEAR(fecha_venta)='$año'");
$junio = mysqli_query($conx,"SELECT SUM(monto_venta) AS r FROM ventas WHERE MONTH(fecha_venta)=6 AND YEAR(fecha_venta)='$año'");
$julio = mysqli_query($conx,"SELECT SUM(monto_venta) AS r FROM ventas WHERE MONTH(fecha_venta)=7 AND YEAR(fecha_venta)='$año'");
$agosto = mysqli_query($conx,"SELECT SUM(monto_venta) AS r FROM ventas WHERE MONTH(fecha_venta)=8 AND YEAR(fecha_venta)='$año'");
$septiembre = mysqli_query($conx,"SELECT SUM(monto_venta) AS r FROM ventas WHERE MONTH(fecha_venta)=9 AND YEAR(fecha_venta)='$año'");
$octubre = mysqli_query($conx,"SELECT SUM(monto_venta) AS r FROM ventas WHERE MONTH(fecha_venta)=10 AND YEAR(fecha_venta)='$año'");
$noviembre = mysqli_query($conx,"SELECT SUM(monto_venta) AS r FROM ventas WHERE MONTH(fecha_venta)=11 AND YEAR(fecha_venta)='$año'");
$diciembre = mysqli_query($conx,"SELECT SUM(monto_venta) AS r FROM ventas WHERE MONTH(fecha_venta)=12 AND YEAR(fecha_venta)='$año'");

$enero= mysqli_fetch_array($enero);
$febrero= mysqli_fetch_array($febrero);
.... so on and so forth
$data = array(0 => round($enero['r'],1),
          1 => round($febrero['r'],1),
          2 => round($marzo['r'],1),
          3 => round($abril['r'],1),
          4 => round($mayo['r'],1),
          5 => round($junio['r'],1),
          6 => round($julio['r'],1),
          7 => round($agosto['r'],1),
          8 => round($septiembre['r'],1),
          9 => round($octubre['r'],1),
          10 => round($noviembre['r'],1),
          11 => round($diciembre['r'],1)
          );             

echo json_encode($data);


?>
```

Where `$conx` is a variable of the mysqli connection.

So if what variable that you've put in your conexion.php then change it.

Good luck.

Comment: hmm now  mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

Comment: edit your conexion.php and let's find what will be the error.

Comment: still same error when change connection

Comment: try not to array first, `$data = $enero;` if it works it's in the array code that has the problem

Comment: still dont work :)

Comment: I think problem are in SQL syntax

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to create a function that does that
Like this

`<?php
include('conexion.php');
function mySqlQuery($connection, $statement)
{`

```
$stat = mysqli_query($Yourconnection, $Yourstatement);

return mysqli_fetch_array($stat);
```

`}
$enero = mySqliQuery($YourConnection, "SELECT SUM(monto_venta) AS r FROM ventas WHERE MONTH(fecha_venta)=1 AND YEAR(fecha_venta)='$año'");`

in order to convert mysql to mysqli just add your connection to your database

Comment: this is not object oriented right? (just asking)

Comment: @LecheDeCrema Nope